# where does php.ini file is located in laravel applications?

Tags: php

I'm trying to find where the `php.ini` file is located for Laravel applications, I have a form with more than 1000 inputs I'm trying to change the maximum number of inputs.

Comment: `php -i | grep php.ini`

Comment: php.ini is in `xampp/php` if you are using Windows. It doesn't reside inside Laravel apps.

Comment: @Sarout `php.ini` is only used by PHP, it has nothing to do with Laravel, is like saying "where is the windows system32 folder on the Ping Pong game?".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `phpinfo()` function to check where the `php.ini` file is located at:

```php
<?php

phpinfo();
```

Or simply run `php artisan tinker` in the terminal where the laravel project is and then run `phpinfo()` in same terminal.

Then, look for `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` in the output of `phpinfo()`.

Comment: I've been messing with `/etc/php/7.4/apache/php.ini` for hours, wondering why my changes weren't being applied, and finally realized that laravel was using  `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` settings.